# How to zip all directories including the root directory?

Tags: javascript, php

In my PHP script I want to zip all directories including the root directory,

For example, my script file is `/practice/zip/index.php` and I want to zip the whole `/practice`.

So far my script zips only the current directory:

```
<?php     
/* ZIP File name and path */
$zip_file = 'files.zip';

/* Exclude Files */
$exclude_files = array();
$exclude_files[] = realpath( $zip_file );
$exclude_files[] = realpath( 'zip.php' );

/* Path of current folder, need empty or null param for current folder */
$root_path = realpath();

/* Initialize archive object */
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip_open = $zip->open( $zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE );

/* Create recursive files list */
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $root_path ),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

/* For each files, get each path and add it in zip */
if( !empty( $files ) ){

    foreach( $files as $name => $file ) {

        /* get path of the file */
        $file_path = $file->getRealPath();

        /* only if it's a file and not directory, and not excluded. */
        if( !is_dir( $file_path ) && !in_array( $file_path, $exclude_files ) ){

            /* get relative path */
            $file_relative_path = str_replace( $root_path, '', $file_path );

            /* Add file to zip archive */
            $zip_addfile = $zip->addFile( $file_path, $file_relative_path );
        }
    }
}

/* Create ZIP after closing the object. */
$zip_close = $zip->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dirname(`).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Ex:

```
$root_path = "/practice/zip";
echo dirname($root_path);
```

will return: `/practice`

The second optional parameter of the `dirname()` function allows you set how many parent directories to move up.

Comment: when i use $root_path = "/practice/zip"; it returns the  /practice with errors the errors are as follow:/practice
Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/practice/zip,/practice/zip): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\zip\index.php:21 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\zip\index.php(21): RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('/practice/zip') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\zip\index.php on line 21

Comment: $root_path = "/practice/zip" was just an example to show how to use dirname(). Try using $root_path = dirname(realpath());